# Writing an IEEE document

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

I need to write a document by using one of the IEEE Xplore templates but I don't know how to compile it since that my TeX editors don't recognize this template [I have installed in my laptop TeX Maker and LyX].

The template I want to use is in the following link: http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html

Can you help me please? What I have to do in order to these editors compile this kind of templates?.

Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's tedious to download templates from websites. Most probably you have to place either a `.sty` file in your directory or open the template `.tex` file and edit it. Side note: This is an English-speaking website, you don't have to put Spanish '?' marks ;-)

Comment: the template will be in compressed format (.zip or .tar.gz) uncompress it to see the .tex files

Comment: when I open the .tex document and order to compile, the editor don't recognize "this type of document". Between the files I have I don't have a .sty file but a .cls one and .tex files. I don't know where I should put them.

Comment: @Jose: Place the `.cls` file in a folder your TeXMaker can find and the start a new `.tex` document with the top line `\documentclass{foo}` if your class file is named `foo.cls`. Don't ask me about input files for TeXMaker ... I don't use such editors

Answer (score 8):

1. Download and unpack the archive.
2. Copy the `IEEEtran.cls` class file into the same directory as your document.
3. Make the first line of your document `\documentclass{IEEEtran}`.

   - (You can also load class options as described in the "How-To" file included in the archive.)
4. Compile the document the way you would normally compile a LaTeX
   document. (E.g., enter `pdflatex file` at the command line.)

See other questions on this site about setting up your preferred editor and using custom document classes.

Comment: `\documentclass{IEEEtran}` worked out of the box for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a UNIX system, and plan on using similar templates more than once, here is what you can do:

1. [Download IEEEtran.cls](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html).
2. `locate article.cls` to find where you need to place `IEEEtran.cls`
3. `sudo cp IEEEtran.cls <location-of-article.cls>` to copy `IEEEtran.cls` into the folder containing `article.cls`
4. `sudo texhash` to tell TeX about the new class
5. If you are getting many error messages at this point when compiling the template, then you may need to install the texlive-fonts-recommended package: `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended`

You should now be able to compile your template.

Comment: Please don't fiddle with the official installation and those folders. Make your own texmf reachable instead.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to installing an editor such as TeX Maker (I prefer TeX Studio myself), you have to set up the **LaTeX production environment** based on which your TeX Maker can compile your documents.

No matter what Operating System you are using, I suggest you do the following steps:

1. Install TeX Live first:
   https://www.tug.org/texlive/
2. Re-install a TeX editor, such as TeX Maker or TeX Studio;
3. Check whether the correct path for LaTeX compile tools are detected correctly in TeX Maker (make sure they are in the right path as installed TeX Live);
   e.g. http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION01
4. Dry-run the template to see how it works.

BTW, as a beginner, you may not want to **confuse** yourself by using TeX and LyX at the same time. They are quite different.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link, no installation, `open as template` you can write IEEE paper directly from web browser.  Enjoy typing!

[IEEE for journals template with bibtex example files included](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-for-journals-template-with-bibtex-example-files-included/hjbyjvncdmpx#.VNVUktLF8VR)