# How to write a report template in IEEE format?

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, ieeetran

Well, I want to write a report in IEEE format ,but I have limited knowledge about Latex, so how am I supposed to begin?

Comment: IEEE templates are available [online](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html). See answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222765/28557) also.

Answer (score 1):

To start, at least with TeX Live you can run `texdoc IEEE` in your OS prompt to obtain:

> [image: IEEEtrans]

Otherwise, you can dowload the PDF from [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf). 
As the paper explain, it is assumed that the reader has at least a basic working
knowledge of LaTeX.

See also [How to Use the IEEEtran BIBTEX Style](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf).